# xml cdata returns XML parsing failed: syntax error illegal byte sequence in encoding with xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, syntax-error, cdata

i searched for an answer and couldn't find one.

i have a long xml generated by server. i want to display some of the nodes using xslt.

**the problem is:** when i open the xml on browser i get:
XML parsing failed,XML parsing failed: syntax error,illegal byte sequence in encoding

the error is inside a cdata inside one of the nodes staring with `<![CDATA[` and ends with `]]>`

the error is: `,` and a hundreds of characters like it.

to my understanding this shouldn't happen if its in cdata it should ignore or escape it.

the xml encoding is utf8 .

thank you for your help.

Comment: Could you show us some of the stuff before and after the CDATA?  Where is it located within the XML?

Comment: `<nodename display_name="some texe (text)" element_type="ta" data_type="text"></nodename >`

Answer (score 5):

### The encoding

You say "the xml encoding is utf8".  Your parser is telling you that you're wrong.  It's finding a byte sequence that cannot occur in UTF-8; in my experience that often happens when ISO 8859-1 (ISO Latin 1) data is wrongly tagged UTF-8.

If you have examined the data in question in a hex dump or similar tool and confirmed that it's legal UTF-8, then it looks like you have a bug to report to your vendor.  If you haven't, then it says here the parser is likely to be right, and your data is unlikely to be UTF-8.  Find out what it is, and declare it correctly, or fix the configuration of the server to make it produce a UTF-8 data stream, or use a character-encoding conversion utility to convert the server's output to UTF-8.

### CDATA sections

CDATA sections occur within a character sequence being parsed as XML; they declare that their contents are character data and not XML delimiters.  A CDATA section does not and cannot declare that its content is an arbitrary sequence of bits, bytes, or octets; by the time a sequence of characters is recognized as a CDATA section, the bits in the encoding of the data stream have already been converted to characters; it's too late to say "Don't parse these octets as characters!"

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> it is utf8.
do you know any such tool by name?
i still dont understand what exactly is the problem with that xml?
it seems that the cdata dosnt convert symbols like `,` or`�` to charecters and there are hundreds of them (all in cdata).

Comment: (1) The XML declaration you quote tells you that it's *declared as* UTF-8, not that it *is* UTF-8.  Your parser is telling you that the declaration is wrong.  (2) As for tools for looking at the data in the raw, there are plenty of hex dump utilities around; od and hexdump on Linux or OS X, hexcat on Linux, debug on Windows.  And if you search for character-encoding utilities, you will probably find some. (3) No, CDATA sections don't magically enable the XML parser to guess what character encoding is in use; that's why the XML declaration provides the `encoding` pseudo-attribute.

Comment: oh thank you,i took out all the characters that do problems with replace, and it worked fine.

that dosnt solve the problem in the long run since the xml is generated from someone elses system, ill have to find a way to call the xml as text take out what i dont need with regex and then use it as xml with xslt.

but if im lucky it may be just a wrong encoding problem(in that case ill find the right one).